# How to prevent storing postgres password in tomcat's context.xml

Tags: git, postgresql, tomcat

In my application I have context.xml file in src/main/tomcat/conf which contains following information:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            name="jdbc/tomcatDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            initialSize="1"
            maxActive="20"
            maxIdle="3"
            minIdle="1"
            maxWait="5000"
            username="postgres"
            password="postgres"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            validationQuery="SELECT 'OK'"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            numTestsPerEvictionRun="5"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tradebook_db" />

</Context>
```

Every developer has its own postgres server on his computer, so I guess this information with username and password should not be placed in git repository. Should I put this context.xml file in .gitignore after adding it to repo, so that every developer has his specific user and password? Or are there any other ways to prevent putting password to postgres server in repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always put application passwords in O/S Environment Variables (envvars).

- Can only be read by the assigned O/S user (or root)
- You won't accidentally screw up file permissions (if putting passwords in files)
- You won't accidentally check passwords in to source control (this is particularly important in open source)
- Survives reboots
- envvars are easy to read with most languages
- make sure you don't send your envars to child proccesses

You should follow the principle of least privilege and run your web server as its own user.

In Tomcat, you can use Ant-style variable substitution in config files, such as:

```
<some-setting>${someJavaSystemProperty}</some-setting>
```

You can't use OS Environment Variables directly (I think...).

To use OS Environment Variables, you can put

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-DsomeJavaSystemProperty=%SOME_OS_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%"
```

in `bin/setenv.bat` (or similarly in `bin/setenv.sh` for *nix). You may need to create that file.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/

If you use Spring, you can use OS envvars directly in spring config files using context:property-placeholder.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what the above is for. I am trying to place my `Resource` element's credentials (password, un) in a file that is not my `Context.xml` file (so that `Context.xml` can be committed to a repo without exposing credentials). I tried the above but `${someJavaSystemProperty}` does not evaluate to the value in my `Context.xml` file.